# Proof verification: Differentiability implies continuity (epsilon-delta)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I have never had a formal background in mathematics and am relatively new to formal proof writing. I am trying to prove that differentiability at an interior point of a functions domain implies that the function is continuous there using the $\epsilon - \delta $ definition. Any tips for the proof or for my math in general would be appreciated.

Here is my attempt:

- Let $f$ be differentiable at $a$. We wish to show that given a function $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$ implies continuity $$\forall \hspace{1pt} \epsilon>0 \hspace{1pt} \exists \hspace{1pt} \delta >0 \ni |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$
- $f$ is differentiable at $a$ $\implies$ $f'(a) = {\lim_{x \to a}} \left( \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right) \exists $

$\hspace{5pt}$$\implies \forall\epsilon_0>0   \hspace{5pt}\exists \hspace{3pt} \delta_0>0 \hspace{5pt} \ni \hspace{3pt} 0<|x-a|<\delta_0 \implies |\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)| < \epsilon_0$

- Suppose, for a particular $\epsilon_0$ and $\delta_0$ we choose a $\delta < \delta_0$ so that when $x\neq a$ we have

$$0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}| - |f'(a)| \leq \left| |\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}| - |f'(a)| \right| \leq |\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)| < \epsilon_0$$

$$\implies |\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}|<\epsilon_0+|f'(a)| \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<|\left(\epsilon_0 + |f'(a)|\right)\cdot|x-a| < \delta \left(\epsilon_0 + |f'(a)|\right)$$

- Let $\epsilon$ > 0 and let $$\delta = \frac{\delta_0\epsilon}{(\epsilon+\delta_0)(1+\epsilon_0 + |f'(a)|)}$$ Then $$\delta = \frac{\delta_0\epsilon}{(\epsilon+\delta_0)(1+\epsilon_0 + |f'(a)|)} = \underbrace{\left(   \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon+\delta_0}   \right)}_{<1} \underbrace{\left(   \frac{1}{1+\epsilon_0+|f'(a)|}   \right)}_{< 1 } \cdot \delta_0 < \delta_0$$ and $$ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|< \delta (\epsilon_0 + |f'(a)|) = \underbrace{\left( \frac{\delta_0}{\delta_0+\epsilon}\right)}_{<1} \underbrace{\left(\frac{\epsilon_0+|f'(a)|}{1+\epsilon_0+|f'(a)|}\right)}_{<1} \cdot \epsilon < \epsilon$$
- When $x = a$ we have $$|x-a|=|a-a|=0<\delta \hspace{5pt} \forall \delta > 0$$ and $$|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(a)-f(a)|=0 < \epsilon \hspace{5pt} \forall \epsilon > 0 $$

Thus, we can always choose a $\delta > 0 \ni$

$$|x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

Comment: "Suppose, for a particular $\epsilon_0$ and $\delta_0$ we choose..." How do you know such $\epsilon_0$ and $\delta_0$ exist?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version of what you have done which is more concise and the flow of logic is easier to follow...

$$\begin{align} &0<|x-a|<\delta  
\\ \implies & |\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)| < \epsilon
\\ \implies & |\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}| - |f'(a)| < \epsilon
\\ \implies & |{f(x)-f(a)}|<  |{x-a}|\cdot \left( \epsilon + |f'(a)|\right)
\\ \implies & |{f(x)-f(a)}|<  \delta \left( \epsilon + |f'(a)|\right)
\end{align}$$

So for any $\epsilon_1>0$ we can define...
$$\delta_1  \equiv \frac{\epsilon_1 \delta}{\epsilon + |f'(a)|}$$

Such that ...
$$ |x-a|<\delta_1 \implies |{f(x)-f(a)}|<  \epsilon_1 $$